# Firebase Rules: Invalid property access on 'auth' object

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm using the Firebase Realtime database (not Firestore) and am having a problem with the Firebase Rules.

I'm using [bolt](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/bolt) to generate the rules:

```
path /projects {
  read() { false }
  write() { false }
  
  /{project_uuid} {
    read() {
      projectMatch(project_uuid, this.parent_uuid)
    }
  }
}

function projectMatch(project_uuid, parent_uuid) {
  return (
    (
      ( 
        parent_uuid != null && 
        parent_uuid == auth[parent_uuid].projectUuid

      ) ||
      ( project_uuid == auth[project_uuid].projectUuid ) ||
      ( project_uuid == auth[project_uuid].projectParentUuid )
    )
  );
}
```

The bolt file compiles successfully, but when I paste the rules in Firebase, the following line produces the error `Invalid property access on 'auth' object`:

```
data.child('parent_uuid').val() == auth[data.child('parent_uuid')].projectUuid
```

How should I adjust my code for this rule to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with the following

instead of using auth[parent_uuid].projectUuid,try to use auth[parent_uuid]['projectUuid']. this will ensure that we are accessing the projectUuid property of the auth object correctly.

```
path /projects {
  read() { false }
  write() { false }
  
  /{project_uuid} {
    read() {
      projectMatch(project_uuid, this.parent_uuid)
    }
  }
}

function projectMatch(project_uuid, parent_uuid) {
  return (
    (
      ( 
        parent_uuid != null && 
        parent_uuid == auth[parent_uuid]['projectUuid']

      ) ||
      ( project_uuid == auth[project_uuid]['projectUuid'] ) ||
      ( project_uuid == auth[project_uuid]['projectParentUuid'] )
    )
  );
}
```

IMPORTENT EDIT: use

```
data.child('parent_uuid').val() == auth[data.child('parent_uuid').val()].projectUuid
```

try it and let me know

Comment: That unfortunately made no difference and still produced the same error.

Comment: can you try `data.child('parent_uuid').val() == auth[data.child('parent_uuid').val()].projectUuid` ,and tell me

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks, that indeed resolves the error. Any ideas how I could adjust the bold code to make it compile correctly? (would hate to have to manually adjust this, since I have something similar in many places). Can we consider this a bug in https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/bolt? (which I know is no longer maintained)

Comment: give me some time ,i will go through it .

Comment: i do not have much idea about it , but i study about it and will suggest to go with manual way , also as provided it is no longer maintained . so i will consider the manual as a better option then bolt .

Comment: P.S. Changing `parent_uuid == auth[parent_uuid].projectUuid` to `parent_uuid == auth[parent_uuid.val()].projectUuid` in the bolt file, compiles in the correct FB rules.

Comment: i though you already tried it in this way but it is good to hear anyway ;)